# Where in WAMP can I activate libcurl?

Tags: wamp, libcurl

When I have tried to activate this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/video-thumbnails/

this message appear after I tried to activate it:

> Sorry, but this plugin requires libcurl to be activated on your
>   server.

So my question is where in WAMP can I activate this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, look at this site: http://joshuamcginnis.com/2008/09/16/how-to-enable-libcurl-in-wamp/

Comment: Hmm, I tried . In fact all things mentioned there I have alreade done in both files. so I didn't need to change anything. However, not working for me. In the comments on that site are people that are having the same problem. Any advice?

Comment: Try to check if you don't really have libcurl installed, like try to use a function (like curl_init()) and see if the php says function not found. If php doesn't show any error maybe the problem is something else.